# I saw many object.addActionListen(this), what's the meaning of it?

Tags: java, this, actionlistener, jcomponent

For example:

```
import acm.gui.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class TemperatureConverter extends Program {
private IntField fahrenheitField;
public void init() {
    fahrenheitField = new IntField(32);
    fahrenheitField.addActionListener(this);
}
}
```

So assume I know `TemperatureConverter` is a subclass of `ActionListener`, what does `fahrenheitField.addActionListener(this);` actually mean? Cause I'm like "ah, this whole screen now shows an instance of my TemperatureConverter", and whats the meaning of passing it to its `fahrenheitField` as a `ActionListener`?

Comment: Can you show some more code? It's about the 'this' which is implementing ActionListener, not the IntField. Which type does 'this' have? Also, where does the IntField come from?

Comment: `this` is the object which implements ActionListener. So you should look at the class hierarchy of `TemperatureConverter`. The class hierarchy of IntField is irrelevent.

Comment: @JBNizet EDITED.Could you help me with my new question?

Comment: It means you want `this.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` to be called every the user presses the Enter key while inside the text field.

Comment: [How to write an ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you, I get it. You answer really helped!

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes,this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what any of your classes are, but this should clarify the confusion

1. If `IntField` or any of its superclasses declare an `addActionListener(ActionListener al)` method, then you need to pass to it "an `ActionListener`".
2. `ActionListener` is an `interface`, so "an `ActionListener`" in the previous point is **any class which it or any of its superclasses implement the `ActionListener` interface or any of its subinterfaces**.
3. If the class which is "an `ActionListener`" is the same in which `addActionListener` is called, then the `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class.

In the following examples, `MyClass` is "an `ActionListener`":

- Class directly implements the interface

  ```
  class MyClass implements ActionListener
  ```
- Class directly implements a subinterface

  ```
  class MyClass implements SubActionListener
  interface SubActionListener extends ActionListener
  ```
- Class is a subclass of a class that directly implements the interface

  ```
  class MyClass extends SuperMyClass
  class SuperMyClass implements ActionListener
  ```
- Class is a subclass of a class that directly implements a subinterface

  ```
  class MyClass extends SuperMyClass
  class SuperMyClass implements SubActionListener
  interface SubActionListener extends ActionListener
  ```

In these example `SuperMyClass` is a direct superclass of `MyClass`, but it can be anywhere up the inheritance hierarchy. Same goes for the interface.

There are also redundant implementations such as

```
class MyClass extends SuperMyClass implements ActionListener
class SuperMyClass implements ActionListener
```

or other odd combinations.

> `TemperatureConverter` is a subclass of `ActionListener`

Semantics, but a class can't be a subclass of an interface (the opposite is, amusingly, not true).